# jQuery selector that finds links whose text doesn't begin with something

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to add an additional limiter to this `find()` method so that the `<a>` elements whose text begin with a string of `Re:` are *left out*.

```
$(document).find(".middletext:not(.quoteheader) > a[href^='http://fakeURL.com/']")
```

The problem is that I don't know of an attribute to represent the text within an `<a>` tag, and I don't know of a selector that only selects strings that don't begin with something. If a `text` attribute existed and if a selector that selects strings that don't begin with something looked like this: `^!=`, then my code would be:

```
$(document).find(".middletext:not(.quoteheader) > a[href^='http://fakeURL.com/'][text^!='Re: ']")
```

How can I make this work?

I suspect there is a way to use `filter()` after using `find()` and make it work, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, as you say, using `filter()`:

```
$(document).find(".middletext:not(.quoteheader) > a[href^='http://fakeURL.com/']")
    .filter(function(){
        return $(this).text().indexOf('Re:') !== 0;
    }).css('color','red'); // or whatever
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
- jQuery:

  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: +1 FWIW, `.lastIndexOf("Re:", 0)` is a useful optimization if there could be long blocks of text. Or better, ES6's `.startsWith("Re:")` for both clarity and optimization.